# Can I override the url npm pulls a package from?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a legacy project which depends on a specific version of an npm package which through a dependency chain depends on a specific npm package of phantomjs, the binaries of which are no longer online at the registered location. This breaks the project's build.

Updating package versions is not an option.

I can fool npm by manually fetching the required version of phantomjs and dropping it into my system's download folder, but this is a workaround, I want a cleaner fix, ideally something that sits in a config script.

Can I, in my project's package.json or .npmrc files, force npm to use another url for a package @ some version, every time "npm install" is run for that project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that this is possible using npm-shrinkwrap (https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks). Basically, you add an npm-shrinkwrap.json file to your project, alongside package.json. In the shrinkwrap file, you can override any specific package listed in package.json - anywhere in that package's dependency chain, you specify a URL to fetch a dependency package from.

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "dependencies": {
    "A" : {
      "version" :"1.2.1",
      "dependencies": {
      "B": {
        "version": "https://myBForkUrl.git"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If MyProject depeneds on package A, which in turn depends on B, but B is unmaintained and has a critical bug, I can roll my own fork of B, fix the bug and host it at https://myBForkUrl.git, without also having to fork A. Based on NPM's documentation it looks like this overriding can be nested as deep as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is uploading the package to github and proceed as in NPM docs https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#urls-as-dependencies

Comment: I think the specific problem is that the package (phantomjs) is a dependency of another dependency, so adding a URL/git link to the top level dependency does not help. The dependency in between will still point to the wrong version.